# How to split the nginx config across multiple lines?

Tags: nginx, configuration

Especially when configuring [HPKP](https://scotthelme.co.uk/hpkp-http-public-key-pinning/) header (or other long headers in general) it would be useful to split a line in an nginx config over multiple lines.

This is the desired result:

```
pin-sha256="X3pGTSOuJeEVw989IJ/cEtXUEmy52zs1TZQrU06KUKg=";
pin-sha256="MHJYVThihUrJcxW6wcqyOISTXIsInsdj3xK8QrZbHec="; 
pin-sha256="isi41AizREkLvvft0IRW4u3XMFR2Yg7bvrF7padyCJg="; 
pin-sha256="I/bAACUzdYEFNw2ZKRaypOyYvvOtqBzg21g9a5WVClg="; 
pin-sha256="Y4/Gxyck5JLLnC/zWHtSHfNljuMbOJi6dRQuRJTgYdo="; 
pin-sha256="/oCVQg3nP3DroGpFdAbaiYzenycUftqrH3LAyaIal2g=";
```

However for the browser it should only be one line:

```
pin-sha256="X3pGTSOuJeEVw989IJ/cEtXUEmy52zs1TZQrU06KUKg="; pin-sha256="MHJYVThihUrJcxW6wcqyOISTXIsInsdj3xK8QrZbHec="; pin-sha256="isi41AizREkLvvft0IRW4u3XMFR2Yg7bvrF7padyCJg="; pin-sha256="I/bAACUzdYEFNw2ZKRaypOyYvvOtqBzg21g9a5WVClg="; pin-sha256="Y4/Gxyck5JLLnC/zWHtSHfNljuMbOJi6dRQuRJTgYdo="; pin-sha256="/oCVQg3nP3DroGpFdAbaiYzenycUftqrH3LAyaIal2g=";
```

So I've tried some things, but I'm not satisfied with the results...

### First try: Just split it

```
add_header Public-Key-Pins '
pin-sha256="X3pGTSOuJeEVw989IJ/cEtXUEmy52zs1TZQrU06KUKg=";
pin-sha256="MHJYVThihUrJcxW6wcqyOISTXIsInsdj3xK8QrZbHec=";
pin-sha256="isi41AizREkLvvft0IRW4u3XMFR2Yg7bvrF7padyCJg=";
pin-sha256="I/bAACUzdYEFNw2ZKRaypOyYvvOtqBzg21g9a5WVClg=";
pin-sha256="Y4/Gxyck5JLLnC/zWHtSHfNljuMbOJi6dRQuRJTgYdo=";
pin-sha256="/oCVQg3nP3DroGpFdAbaiYzenycUftqrH3LAyaIal2g=";
'
```

This works, but with `curl` I can see that the browsers receives the header with all line breaks...

### Second try: Backslash

Actually in the already linked article Scott Helme recommends this:

```
add_header Public-Key-Pins ' \
pin-sha256="X3pGTSOuJeEVw989IJ/cEtXUEmy52zs1TZQrU06KUKg="; \
pin-sha256="MHJYVThihUrJcxW6wcqyOISTXIsInsdj3xK8QrZbHec="; \
pin-sha256="isi41AizREkLvvft0IRW4u3XMFR2Yg7bvrF7padyCJg="; \
pin-sha256="I/bAACUzdYEFNw2ZKRaypOyYvvOtqBzg21g9a5WVClg="; \
pin-sha256="Y4/Gxyck5JLLnC/zWHtSHfNljuMbOJi6dRQuRJTgYdo="; \
pin-sha256="/oCVQg3nP3DroGpFdAbaiYzenycUftqrH3LAyaIal2g="; \
'
```

However in my case this just added the slashes and also returned them to the browser, so this does not work.

**So how can I do this?**

## Bonus

Of course comments for every line would be an awesome addition:

```
pin-sha256="X3pGTSOuJeEVw989IJ/cEtXUEmy52zs1TZQrU06KUKg="; # current ECDSA
pin-sha256="MHJYVThihUrJcxW6wcqyOISTXIsInsdj3xK8QrZbHec="; # current RSA (nginx 1.11.0)
pin-sha256="isi41AizREkLvvft0IRW4u3XMFR2Yg7bvrF7padyCJg="; # backup ECDSA 1
pin-sha256="I/bAACUzdYEFNw2ZKRaypOyYvvOtqBzg21g9a5WVClg="; # backup ECDSA 2
pin-sha256="Y4/Gxyck5JLLnC/zWHtSHfNljuMbOJi6dRQuRJTgYdo="; # backup RSA 1
pin-sha256="/oCVQg3nP3DroGpFdAbaiYzenycUftqrH3LAyaIal2g="; # backup RSA 2
```

Comment: Could use Lua or Perl module?

Comment: What? How can I do that?
But besides of that I rather want a solution for this in the nginx config file directly. I mean it is not such an extraordinary request to be able to use multiple lines for a config directive... at least this is what I though.

Comment: This still could be in your config file. It's just a question if your nginx is compiled with one of these modules enabled.

Comment: Currently it is not compiled with these modules (unless they are in the default set of modules compiled by nginx), but I could certainly compile a version with such a module... If it helps to solve this "problem".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might need to consider variable nesting that will look something like this:

```
set $PKP '';
set $PKP '${PKP}pin-sha256="X3pGTSOuJeEVw989IJ/cEtXUEmy52zs1TZQrU06KUKg=";'; # current ECDSA
set $PKP '${PKP}pin-sha256="MHJYVThihUrJcxW6wcqyOISTXIsInsdj3xK8QrZbHec=";'; # current RSA (nginx 1.11.0)
set $PKP '${PKP}pin-sha256="isi41AizREkLvvft0IRW4u3XMFR2Yg7bvrF7padyCJg=";';  # Backup ECDSA 1
set $PKP '${PKP}pin-sha256="I/bAACUzdYEFNw2ZKRaypOyYvvOtqBzg21g9a5WVClg=";';  # Backup ECDSA 2
set $PKP '${PKP}pin-sha256="Y4/Gxyck5JLLnC/zWHtSHfNljuMbOJi6dRQuRJTgYdo=";'; # backup RSA 1
set $PKP '${PKP}pin-sha256="/oCVQg3nP3DroGpFdAbaiYzenycUftqrH3LAyaIal2g=";';  # Backup RSA 2

add_header Public-Key-Pins $PKP;
```

Comment: That's indeed a good idea and it works. It is more of a workaround, but it's certainly a way to do it.

Comment: when I put it into server {} I got:
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "s"

Comment: I get `nginx: [emerg] "set" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/myfile.conf:42` when I try this

Answer (score -1):

the `;` is the separator

so you can put things on multiple lines, just end the last line only with the `;`

Comment: That's what I tried in `First try: Just split it` if I understand it correctly. The issue there was that the client received the header with all line breaks.

Comment: then your only hope is put everything on one line. let your editor wrap if that bothers you